# jQuery Post Not Working

Tags: asp.net, iis, jquery

This question is a bit of a long shot, but I will give it a try.

I'm trying to use jQuery's ajax post in my asp.net website, but it is not working.

The simplest version of the code that I tried was:

```
$("#divTest").click(function()
{
      $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "WebForm1.aspx" });
});
```

More facts are:

- I'm using asp.net 4.0 and IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008.
- When I created a new web application and tested the same code, it worked just fine.
- When debugging, I saw that the Page_Init event is not firing upon the request as expected.
- In FireBug I could see that a request is sent to the page, but the response it empty (content-length is 0).
- It tested this on FF, Chrome and IE.
- When replacing the type to "GET", it works fine.

What could be causing this problem?

**Edit:**

I discovered now that if I set *ValidateRequest="false"* for the page, the problem is solved.

What could cause the post request to fail the validation as it apparently does? And what can be done other then setting ValidateRequest to false?

Comment: If you are using that simple example, and are not sending any data, wouldn't the response by empty every time? What is the response from WebForm1.aspx supposed to look like?

Comment: As long as you need no complex ajax post I suggest using the short `$.post();`

Comment: Because you are not posting any data, could this actually be a GET request. In the NET tab of FF what method do you see to the right of the URL?

Comment: Try adding data: {} to the ajax method options.

Comment: @gamerzfuse - when sending the GET request, the response size is about 1000 even when not passing data, so it doesn't seem to matter.

@Zlatev - I actually used $.post() in the first place, and the same problem occured.

@Craig - it says POST. And adding a data property didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your are sending a form, if so you have to send the data to using data property, like this:

```
$("#divTest").click(function()
{
      var sdata = $('myform').serialize();
      $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "WebForm1.aspx", data : sdata });
});
```

then check with firebug the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the data option...

```
$("#divTest").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "WebForm1.aspx",
       data: {}
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't change the situation.

Comment: @Kuzco you mentioned that the code works as expected when you create a new web application. Can you confirm that there is no URL rewriting in the other application? If for example you had a rewrite module to change all URLs to lowercase (possibly to help with stat reporting...something that we do) and then redirect them to the lowercase version /webform1.aspx, it would then become a GET request and you'd loose your POST variables. I'm making the assumption that you might not be very familiar with the entire application....sorry if that is not the case.

Comment: @Kuzco  Short of that, if you have not already done so, set a breakpoint at the OnLoad event of the page in question and check the value of this.IsPostBack and inspect this.Request.Form & this.Request.QueryString objects.

Comment: when using type POST, the breakpoint does not hit in the OnLoad event (nor in the OnInit event), so it is probably not about the request being recognized as a GET request, but about it getting denied or ignored for some reason.

Comment: @Kuzco Oh, it's not hitting onload when you do a post. Well it sounds to me like the problem lies in your application. I can tell you that what you are doing is correct but you seem to have a problem external to your jQuery. So your jQuery is not the problem.